# CloudFront multiple origins configuration

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I would like to start using CF on my website hosted here, I have a few questions that maybe some of you aws guys knows, thanks for your help.
my website have multiple origins that are located over different servers and different ELB, i would like to configure CF in order to collect data from different origins and provide content using different policy and remove a layer of reverse proxy that I've in place right now plus caching some stuff.
Below my idea about the CF configuration:

```
Origins:`
www.pippo.com > XXX.cloudfront.net 
Origin 1: pluto.pippo.com = xxx.elb1.aws.amazon.com > WC
Origin 2: paperino.pippo.com = xxx.elb2.aws.amazon.com > WC
Origin 3: minnie.pippo.com = Apache\Nginx\Tomcat`

Behaviors:`
Origin 1: pluto.pippo.com/*.jpg cache
Origin 1: pluto.pippo.com/*.png cache
Origin 1: pluto.pippo.com/*.* cache
Origin 1: pluto.pippo.com Default(*) NON cache
Origin 2: paperino.pippo.com/paywall/* NON cache
Origin 2: peperino.pippo.com/*.png cache
Origin 2: peperino.pippo.com/*.jpg cache
Origin 2: paperino.pippo.com Default(*) NON cache
Origin 3: minnie.pippo.com/*.jpg cache
Origin 3: minnie.pippo.com/*.png cache
Origin 3: minnie.pippo.com/*.* cache
Origin 3: minnie.pippo.com Default(*) NON cache`
```

Questions:

When my users open www.pippo.com CF will provide the cached content (*.jpg \ *.png in the example) and eveything is not specified in the behaviors will be directly requested (using the default (*) policy) from the ELB to the webcaches. Correct? From the CF or from the user?

How i can prevent that users go directly to pluto.pippo.com ? just a 301 with exception for the CF subnet?

Using this configuration Sticky Sessions will be maintained?

Sorry for the newbie question.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This may not completely answer your questions, however:

1. Sticky sessions: You'll need to forward all cookies (or whitelist the AWSELB cookie) for your default rule (assuming this captures your page requests - unless you're using page extensions, in which case they'd be caught by the *.* rule).

Presumably you don't want your cached content (.jpg .png *.*) to obey sticky sessions.

2. Preventing users from accessing the origin: There isn't an really effective way to do this for custom origin. You can try security through obscurity (create an obscure origin domain) and / or only allow direct requests with an 'Amazon Cloudfront' User-Agent.